# How do I find a job without job experience?

Tags: job-search

I have been in military for 3 years due to the compulsory military in my country after graduating from university. Despite the compulsion, It's not like all people have to join it (only poor one). For half of last year, I wrote and sent many CV to various companies. I applied to their internship jobs but I didn't even receive any invitations to interview.

Comment: What country are you in? Not even fastfood jobs around that are hiring?

Comment: I'm working at family farm now. And yes there are many jobs. But not well paid about 150 to 200 dollars a month

Comment: Still need to know what country are you in. And clearly there are jobs, so what's the problem - you want better ones? Anything specific?

Comment: Do you have unemployment services by the government? What skills do you have? Have you studied?

Comment: They gave me 200 dollars after I completed my service. I studied physics in university. I have basic skill in python, mysql and B1 english. Sorry Can't give me country name

Comment: What did you do while in the military? Did you have duties that required you to learn skills that could be used in a job?

Comment: Most of time I do a paper job and postman job.

Comment: Get some diplomas and publish some projects, that makes company call you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not what you know, but who you know, which makes a difference. Try and get into contact with recruiters or your local employment agency.

Sometimes an opportunity will arise unexpectedly.

If I may speak of my own experience, I once worked for an employment agency. I started off doing basic jobs, e.g. making cardboard boxes, sweeping warehouse floors, etc. But one day, I was at a company doing some similar work, sent there by the agency, and it came out that I had knowledge and skills in certain fields of software development, which were of relevance for the company, so they took me on doing software development. So I got a "foot in the door" of this type of work quite by accident.

Be open about opportunities that may arise. Your first job might well not be your dream job, but if nothing else it is experience. And it might be the necessary stepping stone to get you onto your chosen career path.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to network. Approach people you served alongside and ask if they know of any openings in their or other companies. Either pursue those opportunities directly or determine if there are skills you need. Same with classmates, friends and family. With experience in physics, coding and military (even menial) I expect you to find something.

Or, your CV is poor. Again, rely on your network for help rewriting your CV.